# How to get values ​from within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to get the minimum and maximum values ​​of each of these objects within the following array. I've tried everything I know but the returned value is undefined, how can I do this? NOTE: Afterwards, I need to do the same in a constructor function and in a factory function. Is it the same procedure?

```
    let faixas3 = [
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 6667 até R$ 7777', minimo: 6667, maximo: 7777},
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 7778 até R$ 8889', minimo: 7778, maximo: 8889},
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 9000 até R$ 10000', minimo: 9000, maximo: 10000}
];
const {tooltip, minimo, maximo} = faixas3;
console.log({tooltip, minimo, maximo}); // { tooltip: undefined, minimo: undefined, maximo: undefined }
console.log(tooltip, minimo, maximo); // undefined undefined undefined
```

Comment: use `[ ]` not {},  `const [tooltip, minimo, maximo] = faixas3;`, faixas3 is an array not an object.

Comment: `faixas3` is an array, you're using object destructuring syntax.

Comment: You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the result of which will also be an array (with the values that you specified in the map callback function). Or you can use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if all you want is a "loop" that processes each item.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects. To destructure values as you're doing in the example, you have to specify from which index you want to destructure values from.

```
const {tooltip, minimo, maximo} = faixas3[0];
const {tooltip, minimo, maximo} = faixas3[1];
const {tooltip, minimo, maximo} = faixas3[2];
```

or you can use a loop for looping over the elements.

Comment: Redeclaration of constant variables is not allowed, and overwriting an existing variable doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: yes you have to use var in place of const if you wish to use all three together. I wrote all three together to tell him how he can destructure from each object of the array.

Comment: You will definitely need six variables to store the values OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  function column(array, columnName) {
    return array.map(function(value,index) {
        return value[columnName];
    })
}  
const {tooltip, minimo, maximo} = [column(faixas3,'tooltip'),column(faixas3,'minimo'),column(faixas3,'maximo')];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 'redefine' `faixas3` in several ways using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Here are two examples. The first `map`-result is used to declare variables with destructuring.

```js
const logElem = document.querySelector(`pre`);
const faixas3 = [
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 6667 até R$ 7777', minimo: 6667, maximo: 7777},
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 7778 até R$ 8889', minimo: 7778, maximo: 8889},
  {tooltip: 'de R$ 9000 até R$ 10000', minimo: 9000, maximo: 10000}
];
const faixas_minmax1 = faixas3.map(v => [v.minimo, v.maximo]);
logElem.textContent = `faixas_minmax1: ${JSON.stringify(faixas_minmax1)}`;
const faixas_minmax2 = faixas3.map(v => ({min: v.minimo, max: v.maximo}));
logElem.textContent += `\nfaixas_minmax2: ${
  JSON.stringify(faixas_minmax2, null, 2)}`;

// destructuring assignment to variables from faixas_minmax1
const [f3min0, f3max0, f3min1, f3max1, f3min2, f3max2] = faixas_minmax1.flat();
logElem.textContent += `\nf3min0, f3max2: ${f3min0}, ${f3max2}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```